# Can Referenced CSS vars be overwritten in a selector?

Tags: css

I am trying to overwrite color value here that's not applying in Chrome at least. Wondering if this is a bug or just a limitation of CSS vars.

The --contrast-color I am overwriting isn't taking effect (#fff). However, obviously, normally overwriting --title-color works fine if I define it again in .dark as `--title-color: var(--contrast-color);`

```css
:root {
  --contrast-color: red;
  --title-color: var(--contrast-color);
}


.dark {
  --contrast-color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}

.title {
  color: var(--title-color);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="title">
    Heading (should be red)
  </h1>
</div>

<div class="dark">
  <h1 class="title">
    Heading (should be #fff)
  </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the variable `--title-color: var(--contrast-color);` is defined for the `:root` element while you update `--contrast-color` on `.dark` element.

If you want to have that reference automatically updated, without the need of redeclaring `--title-color`, both the variables `--contrast-color` should be declared for the same element (e.g. on the `div` as in the example below, but I recommend to apply the *theme* class to a common container, like `:root`)

An update on a variable would eventually re-evaluate a reference on its descendants, not on the ancestors: in fact, if the update of the variable also affected the ancestors overriding the *same* property, then it would change instantly, on cascade, the other title too.

So as a result both the titles would be white coloured.

```css
div {
  --contrast-color: red;
  --title-color: var(--contrast-color);
}


div.dark {
  --contrast-color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}

.title {
  color: var(--title-color);
}
```

```html
  
<div>
  <h1 class="title">
    Heading (should be red)
  </h1>
</div>

<div class="dark">
  <h1 class="title">
    Heading (should be #fff)
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of that but I am more curious about the why. In other languages, usually cyclical references are supported. So I am curious if this is a bug or a limitation.

Comment: because a change of --contrast-color would change the reference of --title-color defined on a descendants element, not on ancestors.